# TestNG Source for version 7.3.0

Tags: testng

Is there a way to download/clone the testng source code from GitHub that corresponds to testng version 7.3.0?  I don't see any branches or tags that are for version 7.3.0.

Comment: You can ask the authors that they add the missing tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a tag there. Probably it is added 1-2 days after your check.

Link: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/releases/tag/7.3.0